# Can't write data into SQLite database Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm trying to save data into a sqlite db, i have looked around but the strucutre for the helper is always this, i can't find out what's the problem. I don't get any exception, just is impossible write data into the db

```
public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String QR_TABLE = "QR_TABLE";
    private static final String ID = "COLUMN_ID";
    private static final String C_TEXT = "COLUMN_TEXT";
    private static final String C_DATE = "COLUMN_DATE";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "qreader.db";

    public DBhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE " + QR_TABLE + " (" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + C_TEXT + " TEXT, "+ C_DATE + "TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTableStatement);
    }

 
    public boolean addRow(String text, String date){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(C_TEXT, text);
        cv.put(C_DATE, date);

        long result = db.insert(QR_TABLE, null, cv);
        db.close();
        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Here is the MainActivity file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected static TextView tvresult;
    private DBhelper db;
...

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this, "NOT DELETED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        db = new DBhelper(this);
        Boolean res;
        for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
            res = db.addRow("Prova", "10");
            if(res)
                Log.w("myapp", "Added");
        }
        Log.w("App", db.getValues().toString());
...
```

On my log i see that the result from the getValues() is empty, so the database is not filled, and the "Added" message is never sent to the logcat.

Comment: Post the code of getValues().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `insertOrThrow()` instead of `insert()` to get a helpful exception message.

It likely says that `COLUMN_DATE` does not exist, and the reason for that is a missing space in `onCreate()`: `C_DATE + "TEXT)"` should be `C_DATE + " TEXT)"`. After adding the space you can uninstall your app to recreate the database file with the updated schema.

Comment: It was that! Really thanks, I modified the onUpgrade and create a new version to modify the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query with reinstall your app

```
String createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE " + QR_TABLE + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + C_TEXT + " TEXT, " + C_DATE + " TEXT" +")";
```

Comment: What do you mean after unistall the app?
The database is created by a class in the app, it must be installed and launched to work

Comment: just reinstall your app

Comment: Already tried, even in another new device